# SpringBoot Test Cases not working in the way they were expected to

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jpa

I have been working on a basic Spring Boot Application building REST APIs. I have learnt to write the APIs and now I am trying to write Unit Tests for them. I have written one unit test for the get API and one for the post API. The post API test seems to be running fine but the get api test fails. I am not sure why. I am not sure if the get test is running before the post and hence nothing is available so it fails?

I have tried changing the order in which the tests are written in order to see the execution order changes but it hasn't changed.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ProjectRestController.class)
public class ProjectControllerTest 
{

    private String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    private String expectedResult = "{id:0, name:\"Testing Course 0\", description: \"This is a test for course 0\"}";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProjectService projectService;

    Project mockProject = new Project(0, "Testing Course 0", "This is a test for course 0");

    @Test
    public void addProject() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(baseURL+"/projects")
        .content(asJsonString(new Project(0, "Test 0", "Testing Project 0")))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    //This test does not seem to work. Returns 404
        @Test
        public void getProject() throws Exception
        {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(baseURL+"/projects/0")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) 
    {
        try 
        {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected a status 200 from the GET as the post is working fine however the get returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to you have a base `URL` you should not send the base `URL`, pass only `/project/0`

Comment: @james Sorry, I updated my answer, remove the base URL. this should work.

Comment: I'm sorry it still isn't working. Here's a copy paste of the log maybe this could help a little more.

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /projects/0
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Comment: Make sure that you have those endpoints, did you test on Postman?

Comment: please take a look my answer again. @james

Comment: I tested both the end points on Postman and they both work. I tried deleting the baseURL from within both get and post() methods but they still don't solve my issue :(

Comment: Do you think it could be because the get() is being performed before the post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199095/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-james).